# Not detecting any changes (Angular)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8, angular-changedetection

On click of a button, I am triggering a test method with i as index of an element in an array.
Now, what happens is this test method changes url (which is inside the sMediaData object) value to null or '' and then emits the whole sMediaData to the parent (SocialMediaComponent). and Then SocialMediaComponent sends the sMediaData to the another child of SocialMediaComponent (SocialLinksComponent) and the change is not detected at the SocialLinksComponent.

```
test(i) {
this.sMediaData = {
  profiles: []
};

if (this.d.length > 0) {

  this.d.forEach((val, id) => {
    if (val.data) {
     this.sMediaData.profiles.push(val);
    }
  });
}
this.sMediaData.profiles[i].icon.url = '';
const a = Object.assign({}, this.sMediaData);
this.socialLinksInputChange.emit(a);
}
```

Here is SocialMediaComponent code:

```
HTML: 
<app-social (socialLinksInputChange)="processMediaData($event)"></app-social>
<app-socialLink [data]="data"></app-socialLink>


TS:
processMediaData($event){
this.data = $event;
}
```

SocialLinksComponent code:

```
@Input() data: SocialMediaProfilesData;
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
console.log('YES 5', changes); // NOT DETECTING ANY CHANGES
}
```

[click on this link to view the object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfZty.png)

Comment: can you provide full code?

Answer (score 0):

I would change `data` field in `SocialMediaComponent`

To

`data: BehaviourSubject<any> = new BehaviourSubject<any>(null)`

Then your `processMediaData()` would be

```
processMediaData($event){
  this.data.next($event);
}
```

And `SocialMediaComponent` HTML

```
<app-social (socialLinksInputChange)="processMediaData($event)"></app-social>
<app-socialLink [data]="data | async"></app-socialLink>
```

Accessing the data inside the `data` looks like this, if you need it

```
this.data.value
```

PS: Please replace `any` types that I used